# Where and how should I store tenant DB passwords?

Tags: security, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I have a basic web app that uses a separate, but identical DB for each 'tenant' of the system.  There's a master DB that contains a table linking each user to their copy of the DB.

At the moment, I have all of the tenant DB connection details stored in plaintext in the master table.  I know its not good and is only a temporary measure so I can continue writing functionality.

I can only think of two ways to secure the connection details (see below), both of which seem flawed, so I was hoping for some advice, if you wouldn't mind, please?

1. Use some form of salt and hash method to store the passwords, with the key stored in a local file on the app has access to.
2. Use a third party service (such as Amazon KMS) to encrypt the whole master DB.

The second option I assume is the most secure, but then I'm reliant upon a DB plugin I don't fully understand and a 3rd party service which will reduce performance.

My problem with both of these, is that if somebody was able to inject a SELECT query into my code and access the master table (FYI, all query variables are bound as parameters), it'll always decrypt the passwords regardless of what method I use.  Is this always the case and something we just accept, or is there another layer of security to get in the way of would-be attackers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Good question.  Not sure that I have the answer, but a few considerations:

First consider solution (1) -- password hashing.

If there is an SQL injection or similar vulnerability in your master database, it does not result in decrypting the password.  Instead, it allows the hacker to get the hash of the password, which he could try to invert via brute force or related attack.  If you do [password hashing the wrong way](https://www.troyhunt.com/our-password-hashing-has-no-clothes/), then the attacker quite likely will succeed.  On the other hand, if you use an algorithm like bcrypt (/scrypt/argon2/pbkdf2) with good parameters, then you have a much better chance to resist it.

Also, if an attacker can somehow inject SQL queries into your master database, then there is also the possibility that he can not only read from it but also write to it (you can attempt to mitigate this risk by using read queries with a db account that does not have write access).  If the attacker can write to it, then he can overwrite the real password with a password of his choice, so he wins anyway.

Looking at the second solution, I believe you are correct that an injection vulnerability will just get passed on to the third party service.  Encryption does not help you in this case.  However, if you also properly hash the passwords, then the scenario for the attacker becomes the same as scenario (1).  Therefore, what you are getting from the third party service is not mitigating your worry.

So generally I say that you absolutely must be doing solution (1).  However, the question really becomes what more can you do?  That's a long conversation on its own.  An easy answer is two-factor auth, but that can become annoying to users.  On the other hand, you could consider two-factor auth only when the user is coming from a new IP address or a new device, which combines security with usability requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your advice!  As you say, password hashing seems to be an absolute necessity.  I've already managed to put myself off the idea of full DB encryption, as the performance decrease alone could cause issues in this particular use case.

I'd already used a restricted account on the DB server, which only provides SELECT, UPDATE and INSERT privileges, but I like your idea of splitting these down between two accounts and might implement that later today.

Thanks !

Comment: Also, unfortunately 2FA is overkill in this case and its actually a mobile-focused app, so the user's IP address will be changing frequently.  Its certainly a nice idea though, so given its only a small amount of work, I might have a pop at this for desktop users to add an extra hurdle for somebody to get over.  The mobile API is very limited, so this might be the extra protection I need!  Thanks again!